# Will cloning model query avoid recalling of MySQL query in Yii2?

Tags: yii, yii2

I want to find sum of different columns, and I can do it using two ways as follows:

**1st way**

```
$obj = $modelClass::findBySql($sql, $params);
$clone = clone $obj;


$grand_amount = $clone->sum('amount');
$grand_tax_amount = $clone->sum('tax_amount');
$grand_total =$clone->sum('total_amount');
```

**2nd way**

```
$grand_amount = $modelClass::findBySql($sql1, $params)->sum('amount');
$grand_tax_amount = $modelClass::findBySql($sql1,$params)->sum('tax_amount');
$grand_total = $modelClass::findBySql($sql1, $params)->sum('total_amount');
```

Referring above two ways, which will be more efficient? Or both ways will execute same number of queries?

Comment: Both execute the same number of queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not matter if you clone query or not. `sum()` performs actual SQL query - if you call it three times, you will get three queries.

From microptimization perspective `clone` should be faster than creating the same query object three times. But you will not see much difference - performing real SQL query will be main bottleneck here, PHP overhead will be negligible.

---

BTW: Cloning from your example does not make much sense - you're never using original `$obj` and `$clone` is used three times. You can use `$obj` directly and avoid clonning - it make sense only if you want to modify cloned query without modifying original `ActiveQuery` object.